# Use the first query result as a condition for the second query

Tags: graphql

I have 2 queries like this

```
const featuredArticles = gql `
query featureArticles() {
  articles(where: {limit: 4, feature: true, sort: "published_at:desc") {
    id
  }
}
`;
```

```
const NO_FEATURE_ARTICLES_QUERY = gql`
query noFeatureArticles($slug: String!) {
  articles(where: { id_nin: ??? },limit: 4, sort: "published_at:desc") {
    ${SINGLE_ARTICLE_MODEL}
  }
}
`;
```

The first query will get the ID of 4 latest featured articles, the second one will get all articles available in the database. Now, I'm trying to change the second query to get all articles EXCEPT 4 articles from the first query but I just don't know how to use the result as a condition. Can you guy give me some hint? Thanks in advance!

Comment: array of ids, check in graphiql/playground .... [xxx, yyy]

Comment: Can you instruct me how to pass a result to an array, then pass that array to another query?? I'm newbie, this thing is confusing me :(

Comment: get results, extract ids into array, pass as param

Comment: I tried to extract the result and save to array like this arr=[result[0].id] but the array will be gone when the first query ended. I can't pass it to the second one :(

Comment: what env/lang? looks like js ... how gone? copied simple value exists, it's not a empty ref ... console log it ... did yuo checked how to pass array [in variable query] in graphiql/playground?

Comment: I posted it in a comment, can you help me?? :(

Answer (score 0):

My index.jsx looks like this:

```
const Home = () => (
  <div style={{
    overflowX: 'hidden',
  }}
  >
    let arr=[]
    <Query query={FEATURE_ARTICLES_QUERY}>
      {({ data: { articles } }) => {
        if (!articles.length) {
          return null;
        }
        arr=[articles[0].id,.......,articles[10].id];
        return <SectionFeature articles={articles} />;
      }}
    </Query>
    <Query query={ARTICLES_QUERY} id={arr}>
      {({ data: { quotes } }) => {
        if (!quotes.length) {
          return null;
        }
        return <SectionQuote quotes={quotes} />;
      }}
    </Query>
  </div>
);

export default Home;
```

For example, I want to pass 1st query's result to arr[], then pass it to 2nd query. But the array will be gone right after the 1st query ends.

UPDATE: I'd done it. Thank you so much for the hint